# What was the first martial arts movie where someone plucked out an eye?

Tags: first-appearance, martial-arts

In the Kill Bill movies, Pai Mei and The Bride each pluck out one of Elle's eyes. In Five Fingers of Death (1972), one of the characters has his eye plucked out in the same fashion.

Is Five Fingers of Death the first martial arts film to do that?